predicting parent class based on the prediction of the subclasses
I work on an action recognition task and I want based on the prediction of subclasses ‘action_name’ and ‘priority’ to predict the parent class ‘Diagnosis’
the script I used was inspired by this reference
I changed tho model implementation to this :
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models


class MultiOutputModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, n_action_classes, n_priority_classes, n_diagnosis_classes):
    super().__init__()
    self.base_model = models.mobilenet_v2().features  # take the model without classifier
    last_channel = models.mobilenet_v2().last_channel  # size of the layer before classifier

    # the input for the classifier should be two-dimensional, but we will have
    # [batch_size, channels, width, height]
    # so, let's do the spatial averaging: reduce width and height to 1
    self.pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))

    # create separate classifiers for our outputs
    self.action = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
        nn.Linear(in_features=last_channel, out_features=n_action_classes)
    )
    self.priority = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
        nn.Linear(in_features=last_channel, out_features=n_priority_classes)
    )
    self.diagnosis = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
        nn.Linear(in_features=n_action_classes + n_priority_classes, 
      out_features=n_diagnosis_classes)
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.base_model(x)
    x = self.pool(x)

    # reshape from [batch, channels, 1, 1] to [batch, channels] to put it into classifier
    x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
    
    # Subclass predictions
    action = self.action(x)
    priority = self.priority(x)
    
    # Concatenate subclass outputs for parent class prediction
    combined_action_priority_outputs = torch.cat([action, priority], dim=1)
    diagnosis = self.diagnosis(combined_action_priority_outputs)
    
    return {
        'action': action,
        'priority': priority,
        'diagnosis': diagnosis
    }

the results gave me the value 1 accuracy , am I addressing the problem the right way !!

I don't really see a problem with the implementation, it looks pretty straightforward and clear. What do you exactly need help with?

this implementation doesn't seem to be right in the case where I want to predict the third class which is 'Diagnosis' based on the predictions of the action and it's order.
this implementation is like a typical multi_label classification
